# LISP function to define a recursive function

Tags: function, recursion, lisp

I am looking for some help with a LISP function.

I have to write a LISP function that defines a recursive version of the function:

Sq(1) = 1

Sq(n) = sq(n-1)+2*n – 1 if n>1

If anyone can point me to a helpful website or able to provide an answer, that would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a 1-to-1 translation. Assuming you want Common Lisp, here's the implementation:

```
(defun sq (n)
  (if (= n 1)
      1
      (+ (sq (1- n)) n n -1)))
```